# Support for searching chat messages with a regex-like syntax

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, chat-transcript, chat-search

Often times I want to search for messages containing words with varying lengths of characters, like, `Shhhhh` versus `Shh`, or `Hellooo` versus `Helloo`. It would be helpful if we could have a regex-like system for searching through chat messages. For example, I could type this:

```
(s|S)(h|H)+\.*
```

And it would match any messages containing characters in combinations like this:

```
Shh..
SHHHH....
shhh...
```

I'm simply wondering if we can have support for something like this. Even if this can't be implemented fully, I'd still like to see support for and or `|` token, grouping tokens `(` `)`, quantifiers like `+`, and wildcards `.`.

Comment: I'm all for it.

Comment: I expect only words to be searchable as that seems to be the things that go into the elastic search indexes. AFAIK wildcards are not supported.

Comment: @rene Wildcard `*` works, [but not entirely as expected](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Sh*&user=&room=8595)

Comment: without the * the result is the same. There is a known bug that special chracters like * + ( ) etc are not searchable and are ignored